# VBA Autofiltering with multiple values from a single column

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter, distinct-values

I am using the following VBA in excel to auto filter a "Master" spreadsheet from a secondary tab which features a table filled with formulas and a set of filters Q4:Q12 in the code beelow. The VBA code filters the master to the data currently selected with the Q filters in the table as well as a few other values:

```
wsData.Range("A1:BZ1").AutoFilter 1, Criteria1:=Array(summaryData.Range("D3").Value, summaryData.Range("F3").Value, summaryData.Range("H3").Value, summaryData.Range("J3").Value, summaryData.Range("L2").Value), Operator:=xlFilterValues
wsData.Range("A1:BZ1").AutoFilter 75, "Added"
wsData.Range("A1:BZ1").AutoFilter 76, "Delivery Date Moved Out"
wsData.Range("A1:BZ1").AutoFilter 24, "Inside LT"
wsData.Range("A1:BZ1").AutoFilter 4, IIf(Trim(summaryData.Range("Q4").Value) = "", "<>", "=") & summaryData.Range("Q4").Value
wsData.Range("A1:BZ1").AutoFilter 3, IIf(Trim(summaryData.Range("Q5").Value) = "", "<>", "=") & summaryData.Range("Q5").Value
wsData.Range("A1:BZ1").AutoFilter 5, IIf(Trim(summaryData.Range("Q6").Value) = "", "<>", "=") & summaryData.Range("Q6").Value
wsData.Range("A1:BZ1").AutoFilter 6, IIf(Trim(summaryData.Range("Q7").Value) = "", "<>", "=") & summaryData.Range("Q7").Value
wsData.Range("A1:BZ1").AutoFilter 7, IIf(Trim(summaryData.Range("Q8").Value) = "", "<>", "=") & summaryData.Range("Q8").Value
wsData.Range("A1:BZ1").AutoFilter 8, IIf(Trim(summaryData.Range("Q9").Value) = "", "<>", "=") & summaryData.Range("Q9").Value
wsData.Range("A1:BZ1").AutoFilter 9, IIf(Trim(summaryData.Range("Q10").Value) = "", "<>", "=") & summaryData.Range("Q10").Value
wsData.Range("A1:BZ1").AutoFilter 10, IIf(Trim(summaryData.Range("Q11").Value) = "", "<>", "=") & summaryData.Range("Q11").Value
wsData.Range("A1:BZ1").AutoFilter 11, IIf(Trim(summaryData.Range("Q12").Value) = "", "<>", "=") & summaryData.Range("Q12").Value
```

The code is working as is, however I want to add another autofilter. This one is a little different than the ones I already have functioning.

There is a column in the Master (column 4) which has a number of different "program codes". There is also a Q filter, Q6, which groups some of the "program codes" into a single category. For Example if a user selects Group 1 then the Master would be filtered to show program code A,B and C. If the User selected Group 2, then the Master would be filtered to program codes D,E and F and so on.

I know how to filter based on multiple different range values, would this work the same way as that since the program codes are in the same column? Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: If I understand what you want correctly, you would do it the same way you do in the first line of code with the Array criteria to filter on multiple values at once.

Comment: You should review using `With...End With` statements. [Take a look](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement).

Comment: @K.Davis...that looks like a much cleaner way to do this. Can you give me an example of how mine would look? I only saw examples on the linked page of what appeared to be a column name = and a static value. How can I incorporate the if false="*" into the with...End With method? Thanks for the help!